# Adding banners with text on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header

can someone explan to me how to insert a widget in my header ? I want to be able to put a slider with text in my header..Normally I only use widgets on the website and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe a little more about your WordPress site? What theme are you using?

Unless you're comfortable editing the PHP of your theme, if your theme doesn't include options for a widget block in your header you might have difficulty doing this without the help of a developer.

If the theme doesn't provide this functionality out of the box, a developer would either need to add a widget block or add the slider as static content into your header by adding PHP code to your theme files.